# Switching 120VAC over 70A safely

Tags: switches, relay

Is switching over 70A of AC power with a relay common, or should I directly switch power with a manual switch?

Comment: Use a circuit breaker maybe.

Comment: I've never seen a relay rated anywhere near that high for AC current. If you can find a part that says It can do it in its datasheet fair enough but I don't think that likely. I agree with Andy that a Circuit Breaker is likely to be the only thing that could deal with that sort of load safely.

Comment: It is undefined until you know the reactive current energy stored or capacitive energy or  V/ ESR  current to charge a cap load. Motor surge currents are generally reduced to 5x max rated full load motor current but arc temp on open with Joules of flaming arc

Answer (score 3):

80 Amp is still doable with a contactor.
example: Schneider Tesys D goes up to 250 Amps.
The LC1D80AQ7 does 80 Amps, if you connect them in parallel for AC-1.

Beyond that you will go into motor operated circuit breakers.

---

Read the instructions of your products with these currents!
For example, paralleling the contacts of above contactors requires special jumpers and connection order. And they have a maximum operating count per hour and a minimum interval.

Answer (score 3):

For occasional operation there are 'relays' that can switch 100A or so and are relatively inexpensive. They're used in smart meters to remotely cut power to people who don't pay their bills (or don't prepay, in countries with that barbaric practice).

For industrial situations, contactors are a good choice, though they are noisy (both acoustically and electrically) and draw a lot of power. Contactors are different from relays in that there is not a flexure that carries the load current, rather bridging contacts are used (so there will be two series sets of contacts per switched circuit).

Electronic switching is possible, but much more inefficient than either of the above, you'd waste about 70W, which is a lot of power, and failure mode tends to be 'on' which can be inconvenient or costly.